# Finding Homomorphisms From a Cyclic Group to an Automorphism Group.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group

I have to find all the homomorphisms, $$h:C_{5}\to \operatorname{Aut}(C_{31})$$

Given that there are thirty elements in $\operatorname{Aut}(C_{31})$, do I have to find the order of each of the elements and then see which of them have orders that divide $|C_{5}|=5$, or is there a quicker way to find these homomorphisms than this exhaustive method?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As you said, a homomorphism $C_n \to G$ is just an element of $G$ of order (dividing) $n$. In this particular case, $\operatorname{Aut}(C_{31}) = C_{30}$ is cyclic, so it should be easy to write down the homomorphisms explicitly (modulo finding a generator, at least).

Comment: So, for example, $x^7$ is a generator for $C_{30}$ since $HCF(7,30)=1$ how does this help to find a generator of $Aut(C_{31})$?

Comment: You need to find a number $i$ with $1 \le i \le30$ such that $i$ generates the cyclic multiplicative group $({\mathbb Z}_{31} \setminus \{0\},\times)$. Then $x \mapsto x^i$ will be a generator of ${\rm Aut}(C_{31})$.

Comment: So $\alpha=h_7$ where $h_7(x^a)=x^{7a}$ is a generator of $Aut(C_{31})$? How does this make it easier for me to find all homomorphisms $h:C_{5}\to Aut(C_{31})$?

Comment: Well yes, $7$ is a generator, but that has nothing to do with ${\rm HCF}(7,30)=1$. Note that $3$ is also a generator (but $2$ is not, because $2^5 \equiv 1 \bmod 31$). As anomaly said originally, you just have to find the elements of order $5$ in a cyclic group of order $30$, which is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_n)\cong U(n),$$
where $U(n)$ is the group of units modulo $n$. But $31$ is prime.

Also, homomorphisms are determined by their actions on the generators of the groups at hand.